# use for loop in flatlist react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, for-loop

I'm beginner in react native, and I want to use for loop in flatlist to push require data,

```
    render() {
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList
  data={[
  require("./assest/image1.jpg"),
  require("./assest/image2.jpg"),
  require("./assest/image3.jpg"),
  ]}
  renderItem={({ item }) => {
  return <ListItem image={item} />
  }}
  keyExtractor={
  (index) => {return index}
  }
  />
  </View>
  )
}
}
```

Like when pushing array from state using for loop

```
  state ={
  a: [12 , 13 , 14 ,15 , 19 ,21 ]
b: "1"
d = () => {
let c =[];
for (var i =0; i<= this.state.a.length - 1 ; i++) {
c.push( <child text = {this.state.a[i] />);
}
return c;
};
```

Is there anyway to use looping in flatlist or we can't using any looping in list or flatlist in 
React Native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `state` (array) and then loop through your required data and push them into the array `state`. Then, pass that state into the `data` `prop` of the `FLatlist`.

You can do something like this...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import ListItem from '...'; //import the ListItem here

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    let data = [];

    const images = {
      image1: require("./assest/image1.jpg"),
      image2: require("./assest/image2.jpg"),
      image3: require("./assest/image3.jpg"),
    }

    images.forEach(image => {
      data.push(image);
      this.setState({ data })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {return <ListItem image={item} />}}
          keyExtractor={(index) => {return index}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here, when the component mounts, it loops through the 'images' object and push them into an array called 'data' and store it to the `state`. Then, that `state` is passed to the `Flatlist` as a `prop`.

Please go through this and ask me if you have any further questions regarding this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's look  right, I'm trying another code for that but I will check your answer.

Comment: You are welcome :-) If you got any problem with the code that you are trying, please ask here... :-)